# Extracting *firstly roots* from some lists to plot their pairs values

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have two different lists as [list1](http://speedy.sh/kyVar/list1.txt) and [list2](http://speedy.sh/mDH2n/list2.txt). Their `ListPlot3D` of them are:
[image]
and
[image]

As shown in these plots, there are some points of which `{x,y}` pairs are first pairs that `z` get zero by them. For example **Red** ones for list1 and **Green** ones for list2. The desired and so important plot which must be extracted from two previous plots is as schematic:
[image]

As it is clear the desired is the taking two *firstly roots* of other shapes in one plot as pairs of `{x,y}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, here is a possible approach to extracting the `{x, y}` list of values corresponding to the zeroes of your function when the function is only available through data points.

First of all, I will generate a data list, since you did not provide one. Let's consider for instance the following function as an example:

```
f[x_, y_] := 20 x^2 - 3 (y - 2/3)^3 + 750
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}], 
  Mesh -> {{0.}}, MeshFunctions -> (f[#1, #2] &), 
  MeshStyle -> {Red, Thick},
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}
]
```

[image: the 3D plot with zeroes]

Here is am using mesh functions to highlight the position of a zero contour for your function. However, you don't have the functional expression, but just a list:

```
list1 = Table[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}, {y, 5, 10, 0.2}] // Flatten[#, 1] &;
```

`ListContourPlot` can calculate the contour line you want, i.e. the list of points $(x, y)$ for which your function is zero:

```
list1plot = ListContourPlot[list1, Contours -> {0.}]
```

[image: contour 2D]

We can then extract the coordinates of the calculated line:

```
zeroes = Cases[
   Normal@list1plot,
   Line[a__] :> a,
   Infinity
 ];
```

We use `Normal` here to transform the `GraphicsComplex` expression generated by `ListContourPlot` behind the scenes into a simpler `Graphics` expression, which is easier to handle to extract information from.

Finally, we can plot the `zeroes` list:

```
ListPlot[zeroes, AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 18, Red] & /@ {x, y})]
```

[image: zeroes]

---

UPDATE

I apologize, I missed the links to your data the first time around. Loading those lists as `list1` and `list2`, and using `ListLinePlot`, rather than `ListPlot`, then one obtains:

```
First[Cases[
     Normal@ListContourPlot[#, Contours -> {0.}],
     Line[a__] :> a, Infinity
   ]] & /@ {list1, list2};

ListLinePlot[
  %,
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"list1", "list2"},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 18, Red] & /@ {x, y})
]
```

[image: new lists]

Comment: Besides thanks for your answer I am not understand why you said "since you did not provide one" because in list1 I provided in the address: "http://www.speedyshare.com/kyVar/list1.txt" and "http://www.speedyshare.com/mDH2n/list2.txt"

Comment: Or use your mesh?`f[x_,y_]:=20 x^2-3 (y-2/3)^3+750
plot=Plot3D[f[x,y],{x,y}\[Element]Rectangle[{0,0},{10,10}],Mesh->{{0.}},MeshFunctions->(f[#1,#2]&),MeshStyle->{Red,Thick},AxesLabel->{x,y,z}];
zeroPoint=Cases[Normal[plot],_Line,Infinity][[-1,-1]];
Plot3D[f[x,y],{x,y}\[Element]Rectangle[{0,0},{10,10}]]~Show~ListPointPlot3D[PadRight[#,3]&/@zeroPoint,PlotStyle->Thick]`

Comment: @yode Yes, that would work **IF** you had a functional expression to use in `Plot3D`, but OP only has lists, not a function...

Comment: @Irreversible You are right, I missed the links when I read your post. I updated my answer using your data. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2):

```
Show[ListContourPlot[#, Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> None, 
    ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, #2]] & @@@
    {{list1, Red}, {list2, Green}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

You can first find all the roots by their z value, and then select out the first point that touches zero. For example:

```
ε0 = 1.*^-3;
ListPlot[Table[
  First /@ SplitBy[
    Sort[Select[ls, Abs[#[[3]]] < ε0 &][[All, 1 ;; 2]]],
     First], {ls, {list1, list2}}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]